# Vue.js 2 - vue-youtube-embed how to detect video ended state?

Tags: javascript, youtube-api, vue.js, youtube-javascript-api, vuejs2

I'm using [vue-youtube-embed](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-youtube-embed) to use the Youtube API in my vuejs component.

Here is my code:

```
<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      videoId: 'HjxYvcdpVnU',
      videoLaunched: false,
      videoLoaded: false,
      videoRewatch: false,
      videoEnded: false
    }
  },
  computed: {
    videoThumb: function () {
      return 'https://img.youtube.com/vi/' + this.videoId + '/maxresdefault.jpg';
    }
  },
  methods: {
    launchVideo() {
      this.videoLaunched = true;
      this.player.playVideo();
      document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].classList.add('overlay');
    },
    ready(player) {
      fitvids();
      this.player = player;
      this.videoLoaded = true;
    },
    ended() {
      console.log('Ended');
    }
  } 
}
</script>
```

and the html:

```
<youtube :video-id="videoId" @ready="ready" @ended="ended" player-width="100%" 
  player-height="57" :player-vars="{ autoplay: 0, controls: 1, modestbranding: 1, showinfo: 0, rel: 0 }">
</youtube>
```

The ended() method is not triggering and I am not sure why.

The ready() method is working fine so I am not sure why the console.log is not being triggered on the ended() method.

I can't see an example from the docs on how to do it.

Comment: As the [example](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-youtube-embed/blob/master/example/app.js#L55) shows, it should be same as others. Raise as an issue [here](https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-youtube-embed/issues/new) it this is not solved.

Comment: I don't know how to answer your question but do you know that the `body` element is accessible via `doument.body`? Might help you write less lines of code.

Comment: @jeerbl good tip. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The author wrote me an example and I have got it working following this:
https://github.com/kaorun343/vue-youtube-embed/blob/master/play/Events.vue

Comment: Some details here would be nice as well.

Comment: I don't know if there's neccessary add more details here, but I do really think that the library author should add a list of events with their respective description to short the development, greetings